# STM32 with USB accessible storage

Tags: memory, usb, stm32

I need a single PCB solution for data storage that can be accessed through USB using a computer. I am going through the tutorials on ST's website that teaches about USB protocol and how to program the Micro-controller's as USB Mass Storage Devices (I'm assuming that's what I want for now)

I have been unable to find anything on the subject because my search terms keep bringing up micro-controller to USB drive communication and not an embedded solution.

**I DON'T want the micro-controller to access external USB devices**. I want the memory to be on the circuit board and files to be easily loaded using a USB cable and a computer.

Does anyone here know of a solution? Maybe a dedicated memory chip (soldered to the PCB) that has USB functionality and can be connected to a computer?

Or a type of memory that can easily be connected to the micro-controller? The microcontroller just needs to read this data once transferred.

I have seen cases where people used SPI flash chips but the problem is that these need to be erased before the new data can be written. I'm looking for a cheap, simple solution (if one exists)

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: I do not see any programming questions here. Ii is programming QA site

Comment: For the electronic aspects to it, see [this post on Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495555/stm32-with-usb-accessible-storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with the ST tutorials you have started with, you can check out the ST  firmware examples for the STM32 family you'd like to use for the application (e. g., for STM32F4 they are described 
[here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00213525-stm32cube-firmware-examples-for-stm32f4-series-stmicroelectronics.pdf)).

Apart from the HAL libraries, ST offers middleware libraries for USB integration and a FAT file system, which may make access from the computer easier.
I recommend to use the STM32CubeMX tool to configure/generate a simple project structure containing as much of the required HAL/middleware as possible.

The next steps depend on the question how much memory is needed:

- If it is only about few megabytes, most of the internal flash of larger controller families can be used, and a
  [nucleo](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-nucleo-boards.html)
  or
  [discovery](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-discovery-kits.html)
  board can be used as a hardware solution out of the box.
- Otherwise, find a memory chip that fits to one of the memory interfaces of the microcontroller (SPI, dedicated flash interfaces, etc.) and post another separate question focussed on the memory chip selection/integration - e. g. on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I wasn't clear but my question was meant to be focused on memory chip selection. I just wanted others to know i'm open for other solutions as well. I will post a question to the EE Stack Exchange. Didn't know that existed. :)